# How do I achieve this equidistant layout without calc?

Tags: html, css

Is there a "pure" way to achieve this layout where there is fixed content and equal fluid gutters, i.e. a way without using `calc`?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37j2jazy/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    min-width: 300px;
}

.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-left: calc((100% - 300px) / 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You could use a way to "almost" make it like that by using wrapper divs for each `.content` and style the wrappers to be one third of the body width. Within each wrapper you center the blue boxes. The drawback of that is the distance between the blue boxes is twice as wide as the distance from the outer blue boxes to the body border.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper {
    width: 33.3333%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper"><div class="content"></div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around a bit and almost achieved a solution:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7daunk2o/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#wrap {
    text-align: justify;
}
.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrap:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrap:after {
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If multiple pseudo-elements were possible, we could generate an empty inline-block (the same "empty word" as the :before) as :after(1) and the element with width:100% as :after(2).

Well, I couldn't get it to work. But thanks to you Paul for your answer and thanks chipChocolate.py and myfunkyside for the edit!